# Как реализовать вывод постов авторов, на которых подписан пользователь в laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

Как реализовать вывод постов авторов, на которых подписан пользователь в laravel? Структура базы данных и код моделей ниже

[image: Структура БД]

[image: Модель User]

[image: Модель Rhyme (посты)]

Comment: Добавьте информацию - посты - это rhymes? как реализован subscribe механизм? Где у пользователя отношение подписки?  Если это `authors()` то `foreach($user->authros() as $author) {echo $author->rhyme(); }` - вернет пост по подписке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно получить авторов на которых подписан пользователь

```
$subscribeAuthors = $user->authors() //получаем всех авторов
```

Дальше с каждого автора нужно получить его тексты

```
$posts = $author->rhyme(); //получаем тексты автора
```

Код:

```
$posts = [];

foreach ($user->authors() as $author) {
   $posts[] = $author->rhyme();
}
```

Но я бы советовал вам вынести авторов в отдельную таблицу и с users сделать связь один к одному. То есть в таблице users будут общие поля, для подписчиков и авторов, а дополнительные поля авторов вынести в отдельную таблицу с связью один к одному. И связь с постами строить уже в таблице авторов

Comment: Я уже сам нашел решение, и оно было таким же, как вы предложили.